# Stretch flex item with overflowing content to the full available width of its container

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow

I have a layout like this:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left-container">
      SIDEBAR
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-item">
          HEADER ITEM 1
        </div>
        <div class="header-item">
          HEADER ITEM 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dashboard">
        <div class="nav">
          SOME INNER NAVIGATION
        </div>
        <div class="table-container">
        TABLE CONTAINER
          <div class="table">
            TABLE
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightpink;
}

.left-container {
  width: 300px;
  background: lavender;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.right-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.table-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: lavenderblush;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 900px;
  overflow-x: scroll;

}

.table {
  background: lightsalmon;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

Also on [codepen](https://codepen.io/traceur/pen/RwbEzbP?editors=1100).

Table inside the `table-container` is wider so I want to have `overflow-x: scroll`. The thing is, right now `table-container` class has width specified with pixels, `width: 900px`. 
That works nice but I would like it to stretch to the full available width of the div with class `dashboard`. However if I add `width: 100%` to `table-container`, it destroys the layout and stretches outside of the div with `dashboard` class along with all the other sibling divs.

[image: Items stretch outside of the container]

It seems like the fix should be simple but so far I haven't been successful.

Comment: remove `width: 100%` from `.right-container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea to use `width:100%` on `table-container` is correct. But also use `overflow: hidden` ( or `overflow-x` ) on the `right-container` so the layout isn't modified.

I hope i understood correctly what you wanted. Please check the snippet below.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 15px;
  background: lightpink;
}

.left-container {
  width: 300px;
  background: lavender;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.right-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
}

.header-item {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

.dashboard {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.nav {
  background: lightgrey;
}

.table-container {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background: lavenderblush;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  
}

.table {
  background: lightsalmon;
  width: 1500px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div class="left-container">
      SIDEBAR
    </div>
    <div class="right-container">
      <div class="header">
        <div class="header-item">
          HEADER ITEM 1
        </div>
        <div class="header-item">
          HEADER ITEM 2
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="dashboard">
        <div class="nav">
          SOME INNER NAVIGATION
        </div>
        <div class="table-container">
        TABLE CONTAINER
          <div class="table">
            TABLE
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: This didn't occur to me, thank you. Is there a reason or a way of thinking about it as to why it works this way? If I set `overflow-x: scroll` on `table-container` I would expect `width: 100%` to be relative to the `dashboard` width as it is, not counting the width of overflown items of `table-container`.

Comment: `dashboard` has the width `max-width:100%` which means it has maximum the width of it's parent. which in this case is `right-container`. `right-container` has `width:100%` so it should have the width of it's parent which is `container`. But, having a child that has a wider width than that, it extends beyond that. If you set `max-width:100%` on `right-container` you will see that it has the exact width of the `container`. That is also not correct it should have 100% - width of left-container - any other spaces.